# Power calculation without using BigNumber

Tags: java

How do I solve the following?

1. Calculate X^Y without Big Integer or Big Number.
2. Need to print all digits e.g. 2^64 = 18446744073709551616.

I have written code in Java, but I am not getting the exact result for higher digits.

My code:

```
public class Calculation {

    ArrayList<Double> c = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double a = 2;
    double b = 64;
    double[] d = new double[5];


    public void powerCalculation()
    {
        d[0] = java.lang.Math.pow(a, b);
        System.out.println(d[0]);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calculation calculation = new Calculation();
        calculation.powerCalculation();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the code you've written?

Comment: You could use a array notation to store big numbers. For example 1 digit in 1 array position. `a = {1,2,3,4,5}`

Comment: public class Cal{

double a=2;
double b=4;
double c=0;
String e;
double d;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#########################");
public void calc()
{

c=java.lang.Math.pow(a, b);

e=formatter.format(c);



  System.out.println(e);
}

     public static void main(String []args)
     {
      Cal a=new Cal();
        a.calc();
     }
}

Comment: Come off it Mike. You can see for yourself that it isn't legible there. Edit it into your question.

Comment: What values `X` can have? Any or is it always `2`?

Comment: any values it can hold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mantissa of double isn't long enough to hold the digits of `2^64`.
The straightforward but hard way would be using something like

```
ArrayList<Byte> a;
```

(where `a.get(x)` means the value of position `10^x`) and rewrite the algorithms of add, multiply and power you learned at school.